# Parse.com docset / documentation for offline reading in Dash (www.kapeli.com)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Has any one found a solution on how to get Parse.com's offline mode documentation in Kapeli's Dash? I've been searching and all I have found is the following:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/dux-tJ43jVo

https://www.parse.com/questions/documentation

https://github.com/Kapeli/Dash-User-Contributions/tree/master/docsets

I was wondering if anyone has simpler a solution (or any solution at all). I do not want (and cannot) go to the internet everytime I want to reference Parse documentation.